# Agrupar vértices em função de weights

Tags: r, grafo

Com base num df de ligações pretendo selecionar todos os caminhos possíveis constituídos apenas por vértices cujas ligações verifiquem uma determinada condição neste caso valor >=3

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
    origem = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "F", "D", "C"),
    destino = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "G"),
    valor = c(3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 2, 7, 6))

df <- df %>% filter ( valor >= 3)
```

O objetivo é agrupar todos os vértices que estão incluídos em caminhos com valor >=3 registando numa data.frame o ID do grupo e para cada ID a identificação dos vértices que o constituem (um vértice não estará presente em mais de um grupo).

No caso apresentado teria 2 grupos constituídos da seguinte forma:

```
 ID    X
  1    A
  1    B
  1    C
  1    F
  1    G
  2    D
  2    H
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando *igraph*, pode gerar um grafo a partir de um `subset` e usar `clusters` para verificar os grupos formados:

```
grafo <- graph_from_data_frame(subset(df, valor >= 3), directed = FALSE)

# Ou, se já está com os dados completos como igraph:
grafo.f <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE)
grafo <- subgraph.edges(grafo.f, E(grafo.f)[valor >= 3])

clusters(grafo)$membership
#> A C D B F H G
#> 1 1 2 1 1 2 1

plot(cluster_label_prop(grafo), grafo, edge.label = E(grafo)$valor)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se precisa do resultado como *data.frame*:

```
grupos <- clusters(grafo)$membership

resultado <- data.frame(ID = names(grupos), X = grupos)
# ou, se estiver usando tidyverse:
resultado <- tibble::enframe(grupos)
```

Comment: Obg pela ajuda. Como colocar numa df as 2 colunas obtidas: vertices e grupo ao qual pertencem?

Comment: Vou editar a resposta para incluir.